# Cast not working, syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t6.USERNAME Nombre, t2.RESOURCENAME Recurso, RESERVATION_DESCRIPTION Descripción,
DATE_FORMAT(RESERVATIONDUEDATE, '%M %D %Y de %l:%i %p') + ' a ' +
DATE_FORMAT(RESERVATIONEXPIREDATE, '%;:%i %p') Fecha

FROM  `reservation` t1
INNER JOIN  `resource` t2 ON t1.RESOURCEID = t2.RESOURCEID
INNER JOIN schedule_intermediate t3 ON t1.SCHEDULEID_GENERATED = t3.SCHEDULEID_GENERATED
INNER JOIN class t4 ON t1.CLASSID = t4.CLASSID
INNER JOIN grade t5 ON t1.GRADEID = t5.GRADEID
INNER JOIN users t6 ON t1.USERID = t6.USERID
WHERE (YEARWEEK(`RESERVATIONDUEDATE`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)) AND (t2.RESOURCELOCATIONID = 3 OR t2.RESOURCELOCATIONID = 4),
CAST(Fecha as char)
```

Cast is not working however, says it has a syntax error. How can I cast the field named as `Fecha` to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely unclear what `CAST(Fecha as char)` is doing in the `WHERE` clause.  Perhaps you can just remove it:

```
WHERE (YEARWEEK(`RESERVATIONDUEDATE`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)) AND 
      (t2.RESOURCELOCATIONID IN (3, 4)
```

But, you also need to change the expression in the `SELECT` as well. `+` is addition, not string concatenation:

```
SELECT t6.USERNAME Nombre, t2.RESOURCENAME Recurso, RESERVATION_DESCRIPTION Descripción,
       CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(RESERVATIONDUEDATE, '%M %D %Y de %l:%i %p'), ' a ',
              DATE_FORMAT(RESERVATIONEXPIREDATE, '%;:%i %p')
             ) as Fecha
```

Comment: It's been a while since I last used mysql. Thanks, this worked. Trying to get some dust off of them skills.